# How to search for special characters in Firefox Devtools Network Monitor Search?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox, when you open the Developer Tools and go Network-> Spyglass icon, you can search the content of requests and responses.  I've got a bunch of responses in the Network Monitor that contain HL7 which uses pipes as separators, so I need to search for something like |X|.  If I search for X, I get too many results.  However when I add a pipe to get more useful results, instead I get no results, Firefox just perpetually searches.  I'm hoping there's a way to escape special characters, and you can point out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Network Monitor (in Firefox 102.0 at least), which I just filed as https://bugzil.la/1777882.

If you escape the pipes (or generally the special characters) with a backslash, you should get the expected results after some waiting time.